# ssh stop at SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent while while connecting to LXC container

Tags: ssh, lxc

I can't connect to a lxc container via ssh, when running on the verbose mode it gives the following debug messages :

```
moelf@moelf:/$ ssh -v root@10.0.3.13
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.3.13 [10.0.3.13] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/moelf/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/moelf/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/moelf/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/moelf/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/moelf/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/moelf/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/moelf/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/moelf/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.0.3.13:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by 10.0.3.13 port 22
```

I looked all over the internet but all the solution seems not working for me.

PS : I can connect to other LXC Containers on the same machine.